# PHP | Проблема с namespace

Tags: php, namespace

**pet.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\PetException as PetException;
use App\MinEnergyException as MinEnergyException;
use App\MaxEnergyException as MaxEnergyException;

final class Pet
{
    private function checkEnergy()
    {
        if ($this->energy <= $this->min) {
            throw new MinEnergyException;
        }

        if ($this->energy > $this->max) {
            throw new MaxEnergyException;
        }
    }
}
```

**pet_exception.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

class PetException extends \Exception
{

}

class MinEnergyException extends PetException
{
    protected $message = 'MinEnergyError: the minimum energy must be at least 1!';
}

class MaxEnergyException extends PetException
{
    protected $message = 'MaxEnergyError: the maximum energy should not be more than 100!';
}
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php

use App\Pet as Pet;
use App\PetException as PetException;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    $toby = new Pet('toby', 8, 0);
} catch (PetException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "App\MinEnergyException" not found in C:\My\Soft\OpenServer\domains\new.loc\MyProjects\pet-bot\app\classes\pet.php:88 Stack trace: #0 C:\My\Soft\OpenServer\domains\new.loc\MyProjects\pet-bot\app\classes\pet.php(20): App\Pet->checkEnergy() #1 C:\My\Soft\OpenServer\domains\new.loc\MyProjects\pet-bot\index.php(11): App\Pet->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in C:\My\Soft\OpenServer\domains\new.loc\MyProjects\pet-bot\app\classes\pet.php on line 88
```

Это часть кода, где задействовано исключение.

Comment: По идее ты не можешь использовать use до того, как подлючил autoload

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев ЧЕГО?

Comment: @Ипатьев просто, как они подхватятся тогда?

Comment: кто "они"? что именно должно подхватываться?

Comment: @karashal вам надо разобраться, как работает используемый вами автолоад. Судя по всему, вы пытаетесь использовать PSR-4.  В каком-по-вашему, файле, автолоадер будет искать класс MinEnergyException ?

Comment: @Ипатьев в composer.json :  `"App\\" : "app/classes"`. Да, psr-4.

Comment: Я повторю свой вопрос ещё раз. в каком **файле** автолоадер должен, по-вашему, искать класс MinEnergyException?

Comment: @Ипатьев в том файле, где он был объявлен: `pet_exception.php`.

Comment: Дааа? то есть автолоадер должен использовать телепатию? каким-то образом догадаться, что класс MinEnergyException  определён в pet_exception.php и загрузить именно его?

Comment: посмотрите в поисковике `composer classmap`. С текущей структурой каталогов - это то что вам нужно

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам надо разобраться как работает автозагрузка. Для начала попробуйте обойтись без автозагрузчика composer'а. Напишите свой автозагрузчик и разберитесь как это работает. Когда вы поймёте принцип, то прочитайте [соглашение об автозагрузке](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), которое использует composer. После этого вам станет ясно как правильно написать composer.json в своём проекте и всё заработает.

Для начала (в целях изучения php) удалите подключение автозагрузчика cpmposer'а (строчку `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`). Вместо неё напишите свою функцию автозагрузки.

Например так:

```php
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    require_once strtr(ltrim($className, '\\'), '\\', '/').'.php';
});
```

То есть, когда потребуется подключить класс `\App\MinEnergyException`, функция подключит файл `App/MinEnergyException.php`. Чтобы это заработало, класс `\App\MinEnergyException` должен быть определён в файле `App/MinEnergyException.php` (а не `pet_exception.php`).

Конечно внутри автозагрузчика может быть любая логика и вы можете написать и так:

```php
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    if ($className == '\App\MinEnergyException') {
        require_once 'pet_exception.php';
    } else {
        // ...
    }
});
```

И тогда автозагрузчик подключит именно `pet_exception.php`. Но подумайте какой будет бардак в автозагрузке, если автор каждой библиотеки (а в большом проекте могут использоваться тысячи сторонних библиотек) будет писать свой хитрый автозагрузчик. Лучше уж что-то вроде первого варианта.

PSR-4 -- это соглашение как писать автозагрузчик и называть файлы с классами. Если вы придерживаетесь этого соглашения, то автозагрузчик композера сможет загрузить классы вашего приложения так же как и классы сторонних библиотек. Вам нужно просто правильно называть файлы с классами.

Теперь можете удалить собственный учебный автозагрузчик и [настроить автозагрузчик](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) composer'а. После настройки перегенерируйте автозагрузчик (выполните `composer install`) и подключите автозагрузку как было раньше (`require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`).

Comment: так вот автор пишет, что у него psr-4, хотя его там даже рядом нет

Comment: @ArchDemon скорее всего автор имеет ввиду что psr-4 написано в секции autoload в его composer.json. Просто он пока не понимает, что означает эта строчка.